Deleting an element inside an Iframe that is using an external website. HTML, JS/Jquery
For example, I have an iframe in which id="myFrame" and src="https://google.com".
How can I remove/hide the google logo image using javascript or jquery. The id of the Google logo image is "hplogo". I also don't know if this is possible or not.
I used this code to try to delete the logo image, however did this didn't work:
$("#myFrame").contents().find($("#hplogo")).remove()

How can I fix this?

iframe will sorta act like two different web pages shown in one browser. Information has to be passed between them, not a direct interaction. If you don't own the source page, you probably can't interact with it the way you're expecting to

Imagine you create dank.com and load inside an iframe bank.com and want to remove some buttons and assign listeners to the inputs in order to send values to other places... Unless bank.com is in your domain - obviously that's something you cannot (and should not be able) to achieve thanks to same origin x frame options.

Also, there's no need to wrap your selector into a new jQuery instance, just use .find("#hplogo") and read https://api.jquery.com/find/
